# CMake, Ninja & Visual Studio 2019 rebuild everything

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, ninja

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with CMake support and Ninja as generator. Everytime I hit the play button for debugging, VS will rebuild my whole project from scratch, even libraries, even though I did not even changed main.cpp. My project is structured this way

```
+--lib
|  +--demo
|     +--lib
|     |  + geometry
|     |  + [...]
|     +--include
|     |  + library.h
|     |  + library_other.h
|     +--src
|     |  + library.cpp
|     |  + library_other.cpp
|     +--CMakeLists.txt
+--src
|  +--main.cpp
+-- CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is demo CMakeLists.txt (I'm using vcpkg for dependencies such as glfw & freetype)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project(Demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_library (Demo 
    "src/library.cpp"
    "src/library_other.cpp"
)

target_include_directories(Demo
    PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    PRIVATE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
)

# Setup OpenGL and glew
target_compile_definitions(Demo PUBLIC DEMO_USE_OPENGL)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW 2.1 REQUIRED)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(Demo PRIVATE OpenGL::GL GLEW::GLEW)
endif()

# Link RtAudio
target_compile_definitions(Demo PUBLIC DEMO_USE_RTAUDIO)
target_compile_definitions(Demo PRIVATE __WINDOWS_DS__)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/rtaudio)

# Link GLFW3
target_compile_definitions(Demo PUBLIC DEMO_USE_GLFW3)
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Demo PRIVATE glfw)

# Third party libs
find_package(freetype CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Demo PRIVATE freetype)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/geometry/include)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/utf8)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/stb)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/minimp3)
target_include_directories(Demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/miniz)
target_include_directories(Demo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/entt)

# Enable UNICODE in windows)
target_compile_definitions(Demo PUBLIC UNICODE)
# Ensure UTF8 at runtime
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " /Zc:__cplusplus")
add_compile_options("$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
```

And here is main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

project(DemoBase)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(lib/demo)

add_executable(DemoBase
    "src/main.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(DemoBase)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET DemoBase POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/demo/lib/glew/bin/glew32.dll"
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:DemoBase>
)
```

The output is always the same : everything is recompiled

```
>------ Générer démarré : projet : CMakeLists, configuration : Debug ------
  [1/5] Building CXX object lib\demo\CMakeFiles\Demo.dir\src\library_other.cpp.obj
  [2/5] Building CXX object lib\demo\CMakeFiles\Demo.dir\src\library.cpp.obj
  [3/5] Linking CXX static library lib\demo\Demo.lib
  [4/5] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\DemoBase.dir\src\main.cpp.obj
  [5/5] Linking CXX executable DemoBase.exe
```

So there is probably something in my CMake files that trigger a rebuild everytime but I can't find what. Is there any way to avoid rebuilding everything and only rebuild files that has been changed with this project ?

Comment: "Is there any way to avoid rebuilding everything and only rebuild files that has been changed with this build system?" - This is how CMake **should** work. Probably, something wrong in your project, or in your environment. Since you don't show/describe them, we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: What does the rebuild output look like?

Comment: I added it in the post, this is the same output no matter if I changed something in my code or not since the last build.

Comment: Probably, some of your dependencies (OpenGL, GLEW) are on the disk with **impresize timestamps**. Try to start with simple "Hello world" executable and check whether it causes rebuildings or not. If not, add dependencies to it, one by one, and catch which exact dependency causes the problem.

Comment: I have removed every dependencies and every superfluous code to the simplest, but it still rebuild everything. It's only happening if I try to build an executable and link it with a static library. Rebuild does not occurs with a simple executable, even when adding libraries such as GLFW.

Comment: In my setup the bug happens only for ninja not for Unix Makefiles on the same project. Is it also the case for you?

Comment: I have filed a ticket to visual studio dev team, and it seems to be related to an encoding error with CMake, not visual studio they said, check your path for uncommon characters, that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

You might be referring to the Visual Studio 2019 bug they fixed in the latest update.

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/VS2019-still-wipes-CMakeBuild-directory-/1142588

Try updating to the latest update version

If this isn't the case please give more info by what you mean here:

> Everytime I hit the play button, it will rebuild the whole project, even though I did not changed anything in my code.

Comment: Thanks, it occurs even if I do not change CMakeLists.txt, I have updated my question